# Segment failed to show all elements in kony

Tags: android, temenos-quantum

I am new to kony.I am facing a problem while rendering a segment in kony visualizer.

I have placed a label whose height is Preferred and width is 100%

Below that I have placed a flex container,within that a segment is placed whose height is 100% and width is 100%.

The problem is segment scroll is not showing the last 2-3 elements.

The whole setup is placed within a flex container whose layout type is vertical.

Please help.

[image: The sample screenshot]

Here the list of animals embedded within the segment stops scrolling and the last elements cannot be scrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the segment's container height to "blank default" and the bottom to "0 dp".

Comment: What do you mean by bottom??bottom margin??

Comment: Right-click on the form (in the outline view) and select "Select Layout ->" then Free Form Layout... if the form isn't configured with the free form layout, the bottom property doesn't take hold. You will have to recreate all your widgets on the form after this, so maybe make a backup or create a new form with that layout and copy the widgets over.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an extra label just below the segment inside the flex. And try different heights for the label. You will be able to see entire data in segment.